# Consumo de Bateria por Aplicativo

Tags: java, android, app

Preciso criar algo que faça essa medição do uso desde a última carga cheia por aplicativo, não faço ideia de como fazer... Pesquisei e não encontrei nada.

Toda ajuda é bem vinda,

Desde já agradeço.

[image: Tela de Bateria]

Comment: Você quer saber o quanto cada aplicação instalado no seu smart está consumindo certo? Já pode começar por aqui: [Monitoramento do nível de energia e do estado de carregamento](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) que está na própria documentaçao.

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado, vou dar uma olhada... Unica coisa que tinha visto era como fazer quando esta carregando, descarregando, e colocando a porcentagem